# Программно получить версию Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, как можно программно узнать версию Joomla (чтоб значение можно было использовать) и/или как вариант узнать, что Joomla была обновлена.

P.S.: Это нужно, чтоб после обновления можно было перезаписать файл, который не удается переопределить.

Comment: Жаль, что тут ни кто не подсказал. На другом форуме помогли. Если кому понадобится, то `константа JVERSION`

Comment: Пока сохранял картинку, вставлял и пояснял, уже сами ответили :) Уточнение - не константа, а класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По адресу libraries/cms/version есть файл version.php, где определен class:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К этому классу и обращайтесь

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение и за ответ! :)